# Validar o input do angular pelo JavaScript (console do Chrome)

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou criando um código para inserir valores em um formulário Angular.

Eu insiro esses valores pelo console do Chrome... só que quando eu insiro dessa forma o Angular não valida as informações.

Como posso fazer com que o Angular valide esses valores para que eu consiga clicar no enviar?

Alguns prints do que tentei fazer:

[image: Input - vazio]

[image: Input - Digitando manualmente]

[image: Input - Digitando pelo console]

Código (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9esrq):

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formularioDeUsuario: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.criarFormularioDeUsuario();
  }

  enviarDados() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.formularioDeUsuario.value);
  }

  criarFormularioDeUsuario() {
    this.formularioDeUsuario = this.fb.group({
      nome: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)])],
    });
  }

  get nome() {
    return this.formularioDeUsuario.get('nome');
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="formularioDeUsuario" (ngSubmit)="enviarDados()">
  <div>
    <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" formControlName="nome">
    <div *ngIf="!nome.pristine && nome.errors">
      <p *ngIf="nome.errors.required">
        Nome é obrigatório.
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="nome.errors.minlength">
        Nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracters.
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="nome.errors.maxlength">
        Nome deve ter no máximo 100 caracters.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button [disabled]="!formularioDeUsuario.valid">Enviar dados</button>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div>{{ formularioDeUsuario.value | json}}</div>
  <div>{{ formularioDeUsuario.valid | json }}</div>
</form>
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

EDIT:

Tentei usar o dispatchEvent, mas não consegui... Talvez tenha feito errado.
Alguém sabe como resolver este problema?